# TextView BufferType

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

From the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html), there are 3 types of buffer for `TextView`, `EDITABLE`, `NORMAL` and `SPANNABLE`. What is the difference between each of them and what are some of their common use cases?

Answer (score 12):

`TextView.BufferType` will be used for changing the `TextView` in  runtime like insert, setting the different color in a single TextView, style etc.

`EDITABLE` -> only return Spannable and Editable.

`NORMAL` ->only return any CharSequence.

`SPANNABLE` -> only return Spannable.

Here is `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` uses.

```
yourTextView.setText("is a textView of Editable BufferType",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
/* here i insert the textView value in a runtime*/
Editable editable = youTextView.getEditableText();
editable.insert(0,"This ");  //0 is the index value where the "TEXT" will be placed
```

Ouput:

```
This is a textView of Editable BufferType
```

Here is `TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE` uses and This is also written by `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` (because editable written spannable or editable) by changing the arguments

```
yourTextView.setText("textView of Spannable BufferType",TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
/* here i change the color in a textview*/
Spannable span = (Spannable)yourTextView.getText();
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff0000ff),11,"textView of Spannable BufferType".length(),Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Output:

```
textView of  `Spannable BufferType`(Spannable BufferType are in blue color)
```